# How to connect Amazon EC2 with Cloudflare?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up Amazon EC2 with Cloudflare for more than one day. I already added all the information `NS` failover with NS route53 no Cloudflare but nothing works.

Someone got success to connect the EC2 with Cloudflare?

Comment: Can you give us more details?  The output of `dig yourdomain.com` would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Route53 in conjunction with CloudFlare (unless you do a CNAME set-up of CloudFlare); instead [you have to point your domain name to CloudFlare's authoritative nameservers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step-3-Change-your-domain-name-servers-to-CloudFlare).

Adding NS records isn't enough, your domain name's authoritative nameserver records must move to CloudFlare in full.

Comment: Note that Route53 is also a registrar. It's unclear from the question which capability OP is using.